# Aggregate C# groupby in array

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following structure and I want to aggregate over a list of movies to get all the actors and their image.

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"Title" : "Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl",
"Actors" : [ 
    {
        "Name" : "Johnny Depp",
        "NameInMovie" : "Captain Jack Sparrow",
        "ImageUrl" : "Johnny-Depp.png"
    }, 
    {
        "Name" : "Geoffrey Rush",
        "NameInMovie" : "Captain Hector Barbossa",
        "ImageUrl" : "Geoffrey-Rush.png"
    }, 
    {
        "Name" : "Orlando Bloom",
        "NameInMovie" : "Will Turner",
        "ImageUrl" : "Orlando-Bloom.png"
    }
]
```

},

```
{
"_id" : 2,
"Title" : "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End",
"Actors" : [ 
    {
        "Name" : "Johnny Depp",
        "NameInMovie" : "Captain Jack Sparrow",
        "ImageUrl" : "Johnny-Depp.png"
    }, 
    {
        "Name" : "Geoffrey Rush",
        "NameInMovie" : "Captain Hector Barbossa",
        "ImageUrl" : "Geoffrey-Rush.png"
    }, 
    {
        "Name" : "Orlando Bloom",
        "NameInMovie" : "Will Turner",
        "ImageUrl" : "Orlando-Bloom.png"
    }
]
```

}

Tried to get the result using the Linq AsQueryable function, but it is not supported:

```
var actors = Movies
.AsQueryable()
.SelectMany(x => x.Actors)
.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
.Select(a => a.First())
.ToList();
```

How to get this working with MongoDB driver2

The result should like like

```
{"Name" : "Johnny Depp",
"ImageUrl" : "Johnny-Depp.png" }, 
{"Name" : "Geoffrey Rush",
"ImageUrl" : "Geoffrey-Rush.png" }, 
{"Name" : "Orlando Bloom",
"ImageUrl" : "Orlando-Bloom.png" }
```

**Solved with**

```
var actors = Movies.AsQueryable()
.SelectMany(x => x.Actors)
.GroupBy(x => new Actor { Name = x.Name, ImageUrl = x.ImageUrl })
.Select(x => x.Key)
.ToList();
```

This gives the following query

```
[{
    "$unwind": "$Actors"
},
{
    "$project": {
        "Actors": "$Actors",
        "_id": 0
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "ImageUrl": "$Actors.ImageUrl",
            "Name": "$Actors.Name"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but mostly missing on the actual selection of the properties within the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
var results = Movies.AsQueryable()
 .SelectMany( x => x.Actors )
 .GroupBy( x => x.Name )
 .Select( x => new { Name = x.Key, ImgUrl = x.First().ImageUrl })
 .ToArray();
```

So it's the `.Select()` that actually needs the different syntax to what you are using. This gives you a pipeline that serializes like:

```
    [
            {
                    "$unwind" : "$Actors"
            },
            {
                    "$project" : {
                            "Actors" : "$Actors",
                            "_id" : 0
                    }
            },
            {
                    "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$Actors.Name",
                            "__agg0" : {
                                    "$first" : "$Actors.ImageUrl"
                            }
                    }
            },
            {
                    "$project" : {
                            "Name" : "$_id",
                            "ImgUrl" : "$__agg0",
                            "_id" : 0
                    }
            }
    ],
```

Which IMHO is not completely "optimal", but that's what you get with LINQ interface.

There is alternately:

```
var results = Movies.AsQueryable()
 .SelectMany( x => x.Actors )
 .GroupBy( x => new { Name = x.Name, ImgUrl = x.ImageUrl })
 .ToArray();
```

Which comes out as:

```
  [
            {
                    "$unwind" : "$Actors"
            },
            {
                    "$project" : {
                            "Actors" : "$Actors",
                            "_id" : 0
                    }
            },
            {
                    "$group" : {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "Name" : "$Actors.Name",
                                    "ImgUrl" : "$Actors.ImageUrl"
                            }
                    }
            }
    ],
```

Which does not use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and therefore is not "exactly" the same thing, but it does come out to the same result in your case, since `ImgUrl` is always the same value of each `Name` on the `Actor`.